# How can I avoid the Post Processing in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, paperclip

I use Paperclip for Document and Image Processing of both Tiff and PDF.
So Tiff and PDF could be downloaded. Tiff should be converted to PDF and PDF should be left as it is. But when I download an PDF the Destination File has only one page. It seems like the Post Processing of Paperclip makes an automatic convert:

```
convert '/tmp/00c865a9d6c212a20cd851a448969f5520160530-4574-1yqdtq.pdf[0]' -auto-orient '/tmp/00c865a9d6c212a20cd851a448969f5520160530-4574-1yqdtq20160530-4574-8l8k7z.pdf'
```

How can I avoid the Post Processing?

My Code:

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :document, styles: lambda { |a|
  if a.instance.isTiff?
  {
    pdf: {
      format: 'pdf',
      processors: [:tiff_to_pdf]
    }
  }
  else
  {
    pdf: {
      format: 'pdf'
    }
  }
end
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for that was to build an own processor for pdf, which just make a copy of itself. It seems like without setting an own processor a default processor is used which led to that kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

---

Please read the docs:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#post-processing
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#events

You can do sth like this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :asset, styles: {thumb: "100x100#"}

  before_post_process :skip_for_audio

  def skip_for_audio
    ! %w(audio/ogg application/ogg).include?(asset_content_type)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you hovancik. What if I would like to get the same destination file? Like a copy. Is it maybe possible with a processor?

Comment: What do you mean by `same destination file`?